# Cleartool command: Get symlink path and target

Tags: clearcase, symlink, cleartool, describe

I would like to be able to identify symlink in clearcase. I am generating queries from an oracle database containing the clearcase extended path of element versions. It is working well for actual elements, but for symlink, the query is returning me the extended path name of the target (and attributes).

Is it possible to change the behavior of describe command ?
Or at least to identify VOB symlink from the extended path ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the oracle database should *not* include symlinks.

From "[About symbolic links and version-extended pathnames](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21220890)"

> Symbolic links are not versioned and, hence, do not have version-extended pathnames.
>
> Symlinks are not catalogued in the version history of the element.
>   They serve only as a pointer to a target version, and allow you to create multiple access points to a single version.
>
> The symlink can be described ([`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm)) with a simple pathname, as follows:

```
%>cleartool describe -long yoda
symbolic link "yoda" -> ../yoda.txt
```

> The actual text file that the symlink points to can be described with a simple pathname or using its version-extended pathname:

```
%>cleartool describe -long yoda.txt@@/main/br1/br2/1
version "yoda.txt@@/main/br1/br2/1"
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I think our IT department, created a script which feed an oracle database each time we are checking in an element, maybe adding a VOB symbolic link trigger also this script. And that's the reason why I need to identify these vob symbolic links to exclude them :)

Comment: @M4hd1 It depends on the script: if it fetches only extended pathnames, then none of those versions are symlinks.

Comment: Thanks! And is it possible to ask describe command to not traverse the link ?

Comment: @M4hd1 Not that I know of, but check with your IT team.